# How can I parse an nginx msec field in logstash?

Tags: nginx, logstash

I'm trying to handle an [nginx access log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) in logstash.

In order to get millisecond accuracy for my timestamps, I'm using the `$msec` variable. This means that timestamps will be of the form `1430832725.814`, where the integer part is a UNIX timestamp, and the fraction part is in milliseconds. Unfortunately, I can't find a [logstash date format](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#match) which can parse UNIX timestamps.

Is there another way to get nginx to log with millisecond accuracy? Or a way to get the logstash date filter to parse UNIX timestamps?

Comment: Have you read docs? «There are a few special exceptions.... “UNIX_MS” - will parse unix time in milliseconds since epoch»

Comment: I missed that. But I don't have milliseconds since the epoch. I have seconds, with millisecond resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNIX` format literal can handle fractional seconds, so it will be able to parse an `$msec` field.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, using grok filter to map the $msec field to a output field

```
grok {
 match => { "message" =>\[%{GREEDYDATA:unix_timestamp}\] 
}
```

then using another Date filter to convert it to @timestamp field

```
  date {
     match => ["unix_timestamp", "UNIX"]
  }
```

If you want to map to fields other than @timestamp, refer to 
[Logstash reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target)